# Xquery variable not set

Tags: xquery

In my Xquery 3.1 module I have imported my " global variables" through a module import, one of which (`$globalvar:MSGS`) contains an XML document that I generally have no problems accessing through reference to the variable. For example this

```
$globalvar:MSGS//vocab[@xml:id="warning"]
```

will return

```
     <vocab xml:id="warning">
        <span lang="en">Warning! Your changes (OBJECTID) could not be saved!</span>
        <span lang="fr">Attention, vos modifications (OBJECTID) n’ont pas pu être sauvegardées !</span>
     </vocab>
```

But the following is returning an error `err:XPDY0002 variable '$msg' is not set` pointing to line 7-8:

```
1. let $collid := $mydoc//collection-id/text()
2. let $errtitle :=   
3.         <msg-error-title>
4.              {
5.                let $msg := $globalvar:MSGS/id("warning")/span
6.                return 
7.                     <en>{replace($msg[@lang="en"]/text(),"OBJECTID",$collid)}</en>,                 
8.                     <fr>{replace($msg[@lang="fr"]/text(),"OBJECTID",$collid)}</fr>
9.               }
10.         </msg-error-title>
11. return $errtitle
```

But if I remove the inner `let ... return` and make direct reference to `$globalvar:MSGS` like below, there are no errors:

```
let $collid := $mydoc//collection-id/text()
let $errtitle :=   
         <msg-error-title>
                {
                 <en>{replace($globalvar:MSGS/id("warning")/span[@lang="en"]/text(),"OBJECTID",$collid)}</en>,                 
                 <fr>{replace($globalvar:MSGS/id("warning")/span[@lang="fr"]/text(),"OBJECTID",$collid)}</fr>
                 }
         </msg-error-title>
return $errtitle
```

I don't understand why `$msg` isn't set in the first example? Is there an alternative?

---

added test

```
let $collid := "FOOID"
let $xml := 
    <vocab xml:id="warning">
        <span lang="en">Warning! Your changes (OBJECTID) could not be saved!</span>
        <span lang="fr">Attention, vos modifications (OBJECTID) n’ont pas pu être sauvegardées !</span>
     </vocab>

let $errtitle :=   
    <msg-error-title>
            {let $msg := $xml/id("warning")/span
             return 
                <en>{replace($msg[@lang="en"]/text(),"OBJECTID",$collid)}</en>,
                <fr>{replace($msg[@lang="fr"]/text(),"OBJECTID",$collid)}</fr>
             }
    </msg-error-title>
return $errtitle
```

Comment: It looks suspiciously like a bug in your XQuery processor. What processor is this? Can you supply a complete repro?

Comment: I've added a self-contained test at bottom of post. This is eXist 4.7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your test case fails in Saxon with

Static error 
  XPST0008 Unresolved reference to variable $msg

The problem is that "," doesn't bind as closely as you think, so you need extra parens around the return expression:

```
       return (
                <en>{replace($msg[@lang="en"]/text(),"OBJECTID",$collid)}</en>,
                <fr>{replace($msg[@lang="fr"]/text(),"OBJECTID",$collid)}</fr>
       )
```